# Easy way to Automate scanning 100+ pages of my diary using mobile camera?

Tags: home, camera

I want to digitalize my diary. But larger the stack of pages or paper, the harder it is to take a photo of all of them manually with my camera. Especially I don't have any equipment or hardware to put the camera at the top and the notes at the bottom.

I am just asking for an easy way to take a photo of all the pages in the diary.

Is there a cheap, effective method I can use?

Comment: @Ganesh because of your edit, the question doesn't directly fall into the *illegal* category, and is reopened. However, that doesn't make it a great question. The edit makes it look contrived. Do you have a better example than  '500 pages in a notes'? Thank you for trying to work with our system here. :)

Comment: Most brilliant people who downvoted the question can comment on the reason so that we understand and improve it better. It's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to build a rig to fasten your mobile phone into, and get some software which takes picture at a regular time interval. Then you simply start the software, and start flipping pages. Look for stop motion or time lapse software for your camera.

Lets say you take a picture every 3 second, and have a stack of 200 pages, this will take 3 * 200 seconds. In other words 600 seconds, that is 10 minutes to copy the pages and some sore fingers...

Comment: Since I didn't hav enough reputation I can't up vote your answer. This is really a cool idea.. But if you suggest me any application I will accept the answer... thanks for this cool idea. You are really a life hacker man.... Thanks a lot

Comment: Turn on the shutter sound so you get a cue for when to flip the page. Otherwise you could get pics of blurry hands. Also be sure to go into manual mode and lower the iso. Because the camera is fixed, you wont have to worry about hand shake and fast shutter speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Holroy's answer is probably the best one, but I have an alternative. You could shoot a video of yourself turning the pages of the book. Then to read it, you just pause on any open page and zoom in. (I'm pretty sure my Samsung Galaxy S6 can zoom in on video when I'm paused.)

And with a little more work, you could make still shots from the video. For example, you could watch the video on a computer, pause each time the pages are open, and take a screenshot. (And save it as an aptly-named file.)

Comment: This is also a gud idea.. but you know, the clarity of photo will be lost if i record video and do screenshot. It maybe best idea for story book where we are not going to turn before pages again. but i am asking for  study purpose. But cool idea dude.. thanks...

Comment: You're right probably right about the video quality, even if it's HD. (4k is probably plenty clear.) But @Holroy's idea is still probably the best!

Answer (score -2):

You can also take continuous shots of the pages.Just set that camera above stack of quilts and one book if you have that.Go to settings and check for continuous shots.Increase the size for example from 40 to 99.Now in camere mode take the shot by pressing the shutter for long,during this procedure turn the pages continuously,in about 5 seconds 99 shots will be taken.This procedure will fall easy but and do it till end of your notes.Now you may like to edit by selecting best shots.

Comment: Some potential reasons for why this has been downvoted: 1) Most of your options are not related to request on how to copy a book, but rather on various other ways of acquiring the book, 2) You are presenting multiple options, whilst in general it is recommended to have one option (possibly with slight variations) in each answer, 3) The addition where you actually answer most likely came after the down votes, so they might not have seen it (or appreciate it enough)

Comment: @holroy your third point is correct that I did some addition after downvotes for he really wanted relevant answer.But for first reason I would like to say that there were many answers which I have written before,slight different from the question and even then my answers were [accepted](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7659/how-to-open-roller-shutters-silently/7661#7661).I presented multiple ways for I have multiple answers or should I have written each point as different answers?